# Facing issue to setup kubernetes on CentOS 7.3(Master) and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubernetes

Is kubernetes compatable with CentOS 7.3 version?

I am trying to setup Kubernetes master with Centos7.3 and nodes with ubuntu 16.04.
Please let me know is OS versions causing issues in my case?if yes let me know which OS version can be used to bring setup up as mentioned in guide.
I followed instruction as mentioned in guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/#warning but some or the other component fail to work.

Please let me know anything required from my end to dig deeper.
Thanks,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes support mixed version of OS. follow the kubeadm cluster setup process, it will be easy to get started.

follow this document.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: I tried to setup master and nodes on centos using updated docs as in the below link...https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/ i am facing Transaction check error when i try to install kubeadm.Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/kubectl from install of kubectl-1.7.1-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package kubernetes-client-1.5.2-0.7.git269f928.el7.x86_64...due to this unable to install kubeadm and create cluster

Comment: This is Linux issue, you have older version of kubernetes already install on this machine. remove that one and install the v1.7.1. `yum remove -y kubelet kubectl kubernetes-cni kubeadm' this will remove the v1.6 and above package. you run use `rpm -qa |grep kube` if you see any other kubernetes package remove them using `rpm -e <package name>`

Comment: Thanks for help kubelet kubeadm is now working but i am facing issue with docker as below.[root@localhost ~]# sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
[root@localhost ~]# 

tried some of solution which mentioned in some of blogs but no luck.